# How do I get rid of the controller name in a resourceful route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Using 2.3. Is there a way to get rid of a controller name in my route?

For example, I'd like www.example.com/:username to go to that user's profile (similar to how facebook does it).

I could just do

```
map.user '/:id'
map.feed '/:id/feed'
map.friends '/:id/friends'
...
```

but it's not resourceful. Is there a better way?

```
map.resources :users, :as=>"" do |user| ...
```

maps //:id/feed and //:id/friends but not without the double slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an answer, but it requires I monkey patch the ActionController::Resources::Resource class.

...

I just used non-resourceful routes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you are looking for the :member symbol.  I know it works in rails 3, not 100% sure about rails 2.

```
map.connect ':id', :controller => :users, :action => :show do
  :member => { :feed => :get }
  :member => { :friends => :get }
end
```

Here is a link to the documentation if that code block is not correct.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: So this will map /users/:id/feed and /users/:id/friends, but I want to get rid of the /users and just route /:id/feed and /:id/friends (in a resourceful way)

Comment: I don't have a rails 2 installation to test, but try my edits.  I am not sure if the connect method takes a block.

Comment: it'd be a bit different in rails 2, but it appears map.connect/map.name doesn't accept a block/nesting